# SQL Query: Time waited between dates in 2 entries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query to select the most recent raise for a given employee:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Raises.EmployeeID, Raises.RaiseAmt, Raises.Date, Raises.SalaryPrior
FROM Raises
WHERE (((Raises.EmployeeID)=[Enter Employee ID: ]))
ORDER BY Raises.Date DESC;
```

For an employee who has received multiple raises, how can I show the amount of time surpassed between the first and second most recent raises?

Comment: select the last 2 entries and use DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using SQL Server.  You could simplify this with a Common Table Expression:

```
WITH recent_raises AS (
    SELECT TOP 2 Raises.EmployeeID, Raises.RaiseAmt, Raises.Date, Raises.SalaryPrior
    FROM Raises
    WHERE (((Raises.EmployeeID)=[Enter Employee ID: ]))
    ORDER BY Raises.Date DESC;
),
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, r1.Date, r2.Date) AS elapsed_days
FROM recent_raises r1
    JOIN recent_raises r2
        ON r1.Date < r2.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query (it works only if current employee has at least two raises):

```
SELECT  y.*, DATEDIFF(DAY, y.[2], y.[2]) AS DaysBetweenTwoRaises
FROM
(
SELECT TOP(2) Raises.Date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Raises.Date DESC) RowNum
FROM Raises
WHERE Raises.EmployeeID=[Enter Employee ID: ]
ORDER BY Raises.Date DESC
) x
PIVOT ( MAX(x.Date) FOR x.RowNum IN ([1], [2]) ) y;
```